# Clarification regarding this proof

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, proof-explanation

[image]

[image]

I'm trying to understand the proof of 5.3.3(b). Everything is clear except the use a partition of unity argument. But I don't see how can we use the partition of unity argument?

It says that $1 = \sum c_if_i$ but we need something like $1 = \sum c_if_i^m$ for some $m$. How do we get that?

Comment: Saying $1=\sum c_if_i$ is same as saying $(f_1,\ldots, f_n)=A$. But, then $(f_1^k,\ldots, f_n^k)=A$, since other wise, it will be contained in a maximal ideal. But then, this maximal ideal will also contain $f_i$ for all $i$.

Comment: Yes, but why does it have to be the same $c_i$? How do we know $\sum c_i f_1^k = 1$

Comment: Of course, not the same $c_i$s.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what book is this from? Or if it's lecture notes, can you say who wrote them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each $i$, you have an integer $d_i$, say, so that $f_i^{d_i} r$ is a polynomial in the $r_{ij}$. Let $D$ be the maximum of the $d_i$, so $f_i^D r$ is a polynomial in the $r_{ij}$ and $f_i$. Now write
$$
  1^N = \left(\sum c_i f_i\right)^N
$$
for a very large $N$, I think something like $N \geq nD-n+1=n(D-1)+1$ (where $n$ is the number of $f_i$'s). Expanding this product gives $1$ as a sum of terms that involve powers of various $f_i$'s, and each term has at least one $f_i$ to at least a $D$th power (and also some multinomial coefficients). Then
$$
  r = \sum_i f_i^D r \cdot (\text{polynomial in $f_j$'s and $c_j$'s})
$$
which expands into a polynomial in the $f_i$, $c_i$, and $r_{ij}$.